# Cannot install Firebase for VueJS + NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, vue.js, authentication

I am using vueJS to build an authentication (login) page with Firebase, each time when I run: npm run serve I have the same error asking me to install Firebase: `Failed to compile with 7 errors                                                                          10:44:30 AM

These dependencies were not found:

- @firebase in ./src/main.js
- firebase in ./src/components/firebaseInit.js, ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/Login.vue and 3 others
- firebase/firestore in ./src/components/firebaseInit.js`. 
  and asking me to install firebase doing: npm install --save @firebase firebase firebase/firestore. which I did many times, but still the same error.

Here is  my package.JSON:

```
 {
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^7.13.1",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.14.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "gh-pages": "^1.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

node -v = 16.12.1

npm -v =6.14.4

Any idea ?

main.js

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";
import router from "./router";
import firebase from "@firebase";
import "./components/firebaseInit";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

let app;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (!app) {
    /* eslint-disable no-new */
    app = new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      router,
      template: "<App/>",
      components: { App }
    });
  }
});
```

firebaseInit.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig';
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default firebaseApp.firestore();
```

Comment: Can you pls share the entire code of `main.js` and `firebaseInit.js`?

Comment: Make sure you are following the setup in the docs for the "using module bundlers" located here https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: I just added the files required

Answer (score 3):

I find it, just replace `"firebase": "^7.13.1"` by `"firebase": "7.13.1".` and it worked.
I don't know why, but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { firebaseConfig } from './config'

initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

Comment: Please share more details about your installation procedures. The code you paste is how you want to use the library, not how you should install them. (Unless you don't really know how to install in the first place.)